# apply ontouch event any place in Fragemen and display it in Full screen

Tags: android

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/googlemap" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contact_linearHeader1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <com.lociiapp.MapWrapperLayout
                    android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
                </com.lociiapp.MapWrapperLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is My XmL layout File actvitymain.xml:

```
public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements OnClickListener ,OnTouchListener{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.user_detail);

case R.id.chat_btnFullScreen:
        if (isFullScreen) {
            linearChatView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            middlelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            linearChatView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            middlelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
        break;

}
```

}

This is my class i displaying Google map In this page i want tocuh any place it should display full screen . 
i am not able to display it in full screen On Button click . i want to apply it  On touch .

http://snag.gy/H0jcZ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding that code in `onTouchEvent` instead of `onTouch`, Don't implement `OnTouchListener` in activity.

> Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views
>   under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen
>   outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.

So something like this:

```
boolean isFullScreen = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(isFullScreen)
    {
        // make the layout visible if already in full screen
        linearChatView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        middlelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isFullScreen = false;
    }
    else
    {
        linearChatView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        middlelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isFullScreen = true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This will make it full screen if its not full screen while touch event occurs.
And remove full screen if its already in full screen mode.

Hope this helps.